# What are the recommended runlevels for httpd?

Tags: linux, httpd, runlevel

I am deploying an httpd server on RHEL6. I've installed the rpm and everything.

Now, when it comes to service startup, most of the post give as example the following line:

```
chkconfig --levels 235 httpd on
```

which doesn't makes sense to me.

According to [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel) most linux distributions are using runlevel 2 as *Multi-User mode without networking*. So what is the point of running httpd with no network enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't believe everything you read on Wikipedia.

Taken from a live, recently installed CentOS 6 system: The network is started in runlevels 2, 3, 4 and 5.

```
# chkconfig --list network
network         0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

As a practial matter, only runlevels 3 and 5 ever really get used. Runlevel 3 is the usual "no-graphical-desktop" runlevel, while runlevel 5 is used to start a graphical desktop.